# SDL: Listmodes only returning 640 x 480

Tags: ubuntu, sdl

I'm trying to get a new SDL application running on Ubuntu 11.10 and am having issues with getting higher resolutions working with SDL.

After try several different modes, it seems that only 640 x 480 worked, and after running the ListModes function, I indeed get a list back of only 640 x 480. This is true of both hardware and software surfaces.

As far as I can tell, I have nvidia linux drivers installed (GTX 260).

I know this is a bit generic, but is there anything I should be looking at to figure this out?

BTW: Here is the code that I used to list modes

http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdllistmodes.html:

Again, tried for both HW and SW, and only get 640 x 480 back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to my issue. Initially I was compiling SDL myself and was linking against the static library. I switched over to the dynamic library and all the problems disappeared.